# Grouping results and getting only one record per condition in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, group-by, distinct

I have this results:

[image]

As you can see I'm getting multiple same results, I want to get only one row per condition, but I can't achieve that.

This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT
      frld.[SegAmortisation],
    SUM(frld.CurrentLB) over (Partition By frlc.FundReportCategoryId) AS '% of Fund',
    frlc.FundReportCategoryId
  FROM [dbo].[FundReportLoanData] frld
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[FundReportCategories] frlc
  ON frld.SegAmortisation = frlc.Description
    group by  frld.SegAmortisation, 
         frlc.FundReportCategoryId, frld.CurrentLB
```

Any idea how can I do something like distinct of the results and get only one record per FundReportCategoryId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
      frld.[SegAmortisation],
      SUM(frld.CurrentLB) AS '% of Fund',
      frlc.FundReportCategoryId
FROM [dbo].[FundReportLoanData] frld
INNER JOIN [dbo].[FundReportCategories] frlc
ON frld.SegAmortisation = frlc.Description
group by  
     frld.SegAmortisation, 
     frlc.FundReportCategoryId
```

Comment: Column 'dbo.FundReportLoanData.CurrentLB' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Try without partition by, or show me data sample and expected output

Comment: Works without the partition by, thanks a lot, will select the answer once I can, thanks again